# Can't set border to ToggleButton in GluonMobile

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

Using GluonMobile, I tried

```
Border RED_BORDER = new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.RED, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null, null));

var toggleButton = new ToggleButton("text");
toggleButton.setBorder(RED_BORDER);
```

But this doesn't do anything. I looked in ScenicView and the border is blue just like I see in the app.

If i bind instead

```
toggleButton.borderProperty().bind(new SimpleObjectProperty<>(RED_BORDER));
```

than it works, but I can't bind it right now.

How is it working with binding and not with setting? Can I solve this outisde of CSS?

Comment: Does this work without Gluon Mobile, just plain JavaFX? Can you post your View? The red border works for me (testing Gluon Mobile app on desktop).

Comment: @JoséPereda Sorry for wasting your time. I had a css style applied where it set the border to blue. Looks like it overrides the `setBorder` but not the binding. I hoped that the java code will override the css, but I remember something about a second pass in gluon mobile applications. in any case disabling the stylesheet works as expected.